# How to rotate an object from its center when using Object3d.lookAt()

Tags: camera, three.js

I'm drawing texts and computing their bounding boxes. I always want the texts to show their face to the camera and so I'm using following lines:

```
textArr.forEach(function(text) {
    var textGeo = d.geometry;
    text.lookAt(camera.position)
})
```

[image]

It's working fine but it rotates from top left corner and I can't change the axis of rotation:

[image]

How can I make it rotate from center of the text while using `.lookAt()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try center the pivot using 
THREE.GeometryUtils.center(textGeo)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked great. But with a small correction: `THREE.GeometryUtils.center(textGeo)` is going to be depreciated. Instead, `textGeo.center()` should be used